# Python Error, Local variable might be referenced before assignment, variable outside the if condition

Tags: python, local-variables

I am a newbie in python programming practising and made my first basic program

I have to access and print the variable that is local within if function and if I am trying to access it, it shows local variable might be referenced

here is the full code

```
def main():
print("Please place your order by filling the options")

name = input("What is your name ")
while not name.isalpha():
    print("invalid name")

age = input("What is your age ")
if not age.isdigit():
    print("Please type in correct form")
    if age >= "50":
    print("you are not allowed!")
    sys.exit()

item_1 = "burger"
item_2 = "pizza"
print("what would you like to order?")

print(item_1 + "\n" + item_2)
order = input()

item_1_large = "large burger"
item_1_small = "small burger"

item_2_large = "large pizza"
item_2_small = "small pizza"

if order == item_1:
    print("What would you like to choose?")
    print(item_1_large + "\n" + item_1_small)
    selection_of_category = input()
elif order == item_2:
    print("What would you like to choose?")
    print(item_2_large + "\n" + item_2_small)
    selection_of_category = input()

print("How many ")
number_of_order = input()

burger_price_large = int(10)
burger_price_small = int(5)
pizza_price_large = int(15)
pizza_price_small = int(8)




if order == item_1_large:
    result = burger_price_large * int(number_of_order)
elif order == item_1_small:
    result = burger_price_small * int(number_of_order)
elif order == item_2_large:
    result = pizza_price_large * int(number_of_order)
elif order == item_2_small:
    result = pizza_price_small * int(number_of_order)



if order == item_1:
    print("Your Burger Order Has Been Placed")
elif order == item_2:
    print("Your Pizza Order Has Been Placed")
else:
    print("You have made wrong choice")

print("Dear Mr. " + name, "Your Total Bill is $" + str (result))
while True:
main()
if input("Would you like to order something? (Y/N)").strip().upper() != 'Y':
    today = date.today()
    print("Thank you for your order")
    print(today)
    break
```

And i am having the following error 
print("Dear Mr. " + name, "Your Total Bill is $" + str (result))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Comment: None of the `result = ...` assignments in the code were executed before the `print(...)` line was called. So Python doesn't know what to do with the `result` variable, it has no value (not to mix up with `None`)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that result is only defined under if and else-if statements. This means that if every condition in if or else-if statements fails, result will not be defined, yet you will be trying to use its value.

You have two solutions to fix this issue:

1. Make the last elif an else to be a catch-all and have a value for all possible values of order
2. Have a separate else after the last elif to define result to something like "N/A" if all the if & elif conditions fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but if i am doing what you told me, e.g. i made the last elif else     else:
                       result = pizza_price_small * int(number_of_order) but in this case in every case python is just reading it and not the if and elif conditions, if i am passing  else condition with like an empty string or "N/A" at the end, then in this case python is only showing me the else condition everytime

Comment: @TECH360-BIS3300 Can you restate your issue for me? Better yet, it would be great if you could send me the updated code.

Comment: so here is the updated code                                                                                 
    if order == item_1_large:
        result = burger_price_large * int(number_of_order)
    elif order == item_1_small:
        result = burger_price_small * int(number_of_order)
    elif order == item_2_large:
        result = pizza_price_large * int(number_of_order)
    else:
        result = pizza_price_small * int(number_of_order)    in this case in every condition its just displaying the result of else and not other conditions

Comment: Here is another updated code according to your 2nd advice                                                    if order == item_1_large:
        result = burger_price_large * int(number_of_order)
    elif order == item_1_small:
        result = burger_price_small * int(number_of_order)
    elif order == item_2_large:
        result = pizza_price_large * int(number_of_order)
    elif order == item_2_small:
        result = pizza_price_small * int(number_of_order)
    else:
        result = "N/A"                         in this scenario its always printing result N/A in every condition

Comment: @TECH360-BIS3300 is your input always lowercase? capitalizing would mess it up since you are comparing Strings.